# Pdf editor. merging two activity

Tags: android, pdf, android-activity

I am spending my days with practicing PDF editor.
I succed in loading Pdf files. and To edit the file I am using invisible activity over the file. Of course, activity is the 'editor'.
I can write and highlight things.
but the problem is the merging of these two activity.
I have to go to menu and click 'write' button to write.
and then PDF doesn't move any more because i am on 'editor'activity.
so I have to save the writings and exit the 'write'mode.
THis is super uncomfortable....I want it to be more simple.
'especially' those 'saving' part.. I really hate it. 
'move' between two activities should be more natural without saving process...
Don't you have any good idea about this?

please help me out!!!!! new beginer is crying for anwser. Thanks for your time.

Comment: You don't have to use an invisible activity. You can use invisible widgets in the same activity that contains the editor.

Answer (score 0):

You would start your editor activity and wait for the result.

Something along the lines....

```
void goToEditMode() {
  startActivityForResult(new Intent(this, PdfEditorActivity.class), SOME_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

and then wait for the result...

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  if(requestCode == SOME_REQUEST_CODE) {
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        extractData(data);
    }
  }
}
```

Assuming you passed your necessary data as an extra, implementing `extractData(...)` should be easy for the purpose.